# Android radio group

Tags: android, radio-button

Im creating `RadioGroup`, inside that `radio button`. **How can i get the selected values in `radio button` to store in array list?**

```
TableLayout ch = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablechild);
TableRow row2 = new TableRow(Edittextsample.this);
TextView m = new TextView(Edittextsample.this);
m.setText("Meals");
RadioGroup rg2 = new RadioGroup(Edittextsample.this);
rg2.setOrientation(TableLayout.HORIZONTAL);
RadioButton r = new RadioButton(Edittextsample.this)
r.setText("Veg");
r.setTextSize(12);
rg2.addView(r);

RadioButton r1 = new RadioButton(Edittextsample.this)
r1.setText("Non-Veg");
 r1.setTextSize(12);
rg2.addView(r); 
ch.addView(row2,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int selectedRadioId = rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton selectedRadioButton = rg2.findViewById(selectedRadioId);
String selectedText = selectedRadioButton.getText(); // "Veg" or "Non-veg"
```